# How to refuse self-reviews on gerrithub.io?

Tags: gerrit, gerrithub.io

I want to configure some gerrit projects hosted on gerrithub.io so the author of the change would not be able to review (+2) and merge his own change.

Mainly I want to be sure that at least two people are involved in any merged change. How can I do this?

Background: I did lots of searches online regarding this but I seen only some examples which seem to be impossible to apply to that instance
* http://www.bluetrainsoftware.com/2014/05/gerrit-2-looks-good-to-me-and-self.html 
* prolog rules? how to upload them to a gerrit server that is not under your control?